# Retrieve list of revision numbers and their associated revision comment

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

there are a lot of questions similar to mine, but none quite touch on what I'm trying to do. I am using SharpSVN to write a simple client which can get specific revisions of each file out of svn to a filepath of my choosing. I've got this working, however I have to specify everything by hand, and I would like it to be more visual.

To do so, I want to make a revision window that can display all of the revision numbers and comments in one view. But, I cannot seem to get the revision number that goes with each log message.

ie:

r3 - log message that goes with r3 - ( maybe even the author )
r2 - log message that goes with r2 - ( maybe even the author )
r1 - log message that goes with r1 - ( maybe even the author )

The snippet below shows kinda how im trying to go about it but info.Revision aways prints the latest revision only.

```
//SvnUriTarget is a wrapper class for SVN repository URIs
SvnUriTarget target = new SvnUriTarget(tbRepoURI.Text);

//============
Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logitems = new Collection<SvnLogEventArgs>();

SvnLogArgs arg = new SvnLogArgs();

client.GetLog(new System.Uri(target.ToString()), arg, out logitems);

SvnLogEventArgs logs;
SvnInfoEventArgs info;
client.GetInfo(target.ToString(), out info);
foreach (var logentry in logitems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(info.Revision + ": " + logentry.LogMessage); // only read ..
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I should definitely have the client.GetInfo() outside of the loop. However, I do not know how / which method to call to get the info on each logentry like i do with the logentry.LogMessage

Comment: in the documentation the ``SvnLogEventArgs`` class has a ``Revision`` property, maybe you could try that. see [SvnLogEventArgs Members](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/AllMembers_T_SharpSvn_SvnLogEventArgs.htm)

Comment: *BIG GIGANTIC FACEPALM*
Yes, that was what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @TorreyBraman if you have solved it, then post it as an Answer by using the "**Post your answer**" button at the bottom and then [**accept it as the right answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) but do not put it on the title nor use tags on the title as they are NOT required, thanks. If it was solved by some one else, you can ask that person to post their comment as an answer and then pick it as the right answer, ultimately if they don't want to post it as answer just do it yourself and mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the `Revision` from the same place during the foreach loop, that is why it does not change.

The [SvnLogEventArgs](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/AllMembers_T_SharpSvn_SvnLogEventArgs.htm) class that you loop over to get the `LogMessage` value also has a `Revision` property, you should use that to get the revision for that log entry instead of getting the revision from the head

so the code might look something like this

```cs
//SvnUriTarget is a wrapper class for SVN repository URIs
SvnUriTarget target = new SvnUriTarget(tbRepoURI.Text);

Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logitems = new Collection<SvnLogEventArgs>();

SvnLogArgs arg = new SvnLogArgs();

client.GetLog(new System.Uri(target.ToString()), arg, out logitems);

foreach (var logentry in logitems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(logentry.Revision + ": " + logentry.LogMessage);
}
```